# Elsaticsearch Connection Refused

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch  #elasticsearch==7.17.3 used


esDB = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://13.XX.242.XX'],
    use_ssl = False,
    ca_certs=False,
    verify_certs=False,
    http_auth=('elastic', 'elastic'),    
    port=5601,
)
```

Trying to connect to a remote elastic search server but getting this error
ERROR: elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3f597e8430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3f597e8430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)

Comment: can you curl Elasticsearch? what do the Elasticsearch logs show?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch listens on port 9200 for API requests. 5601 is for Kibana. you have the two mixed up in your code, so it should be something like;

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch  #elasticsearch==7.17.3 used


esDB = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://13.XX.242.XX'],
    use_ssl = False,
    ca_certs=False,
    verify_certs=False,
    http_auth=('elastic', 'elastic'),    
    port=9200,
)
```